# What's the population inclusion criterion in an unpaired two-sample t-test?

Tags: t-test, sampling, sample, population, clinical-trials

I'm conducting a clinical trial in London, UK on 200 women suffering from breast cancer and would like to investigate the difference in a biomarker's concentration (continuous variable) among two patient sub-groups. The trial contains patients admitted to a single hospital (one center).

In order to use the t-test I have to confirm that the population from which the sample is drawn follows a normal distribution or is pretty close to that (according to Student's paper). Then I can have an idea as to whether my sample size is sufficient and has therefore been drawn from a process that produces normally distributed sample means.

Here's a list of potential requirements of an individual tested for biomarker A (mg/dL) to be considered as part of the initial population in terms of;

**Disease status**

- Tested for biomarker A (close to general population)
- Diagnosed with cancer and tested for A
- Diagnosed with breast cancer and tested for A

**Location**

- Non-restricting (close to general population)
- Living in Europe
- Living in the UK
- Living in London

I have found similar questions but they barely touch on the details of population definition. Based on your knowledge of the t-test which combination seems the most likely?